# How to calculate the sum of the series of Hermite polynomial?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, summation

I want to calculate the infinite sum of Hermite polynomials, which works fine with older versions of Mathematica, but with version 13 it doesn't.
The infinite sum is:

```
Sum[HermiteH[n, x] λ^n/ n! Exp[-(1/2) (x^2) - λ^2 - I ( n + 1/2) t], {n,0,Infinity},Assumptions -> Element[{λ,x,t}, Reals]]
```

Can someone help?
Thank you very much!

Comment: To which older version are you referring?

Comment: That series may diverge: `DiscreteAsymptotic[
 HermiteH[n, x] \[Lambda]^n/
    n! Exp[-(1/2) (x^2) - \[Lambda]^2 - I (n + 1/2) t] /. {x -> 0, 
   t -> 1, \[Lambda] -> 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]` results in $$ \frac{2^{n/2} e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right) n+\left(-1-\frac{i}{2}\right)} n^{-\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}.$$

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it was Mathematica version 6 in 2007, where the equation gives a solution.

Comment: Looks like answer is: `E^((-1/2*I)*t - x^2/2 + (2*x*\[Lambda])/E^(I*t) + (-1 - E^((-2*I)*t))*\[Lambda]^2)`.

Comment: Yes, this was the result I got with the sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By factoring the exponential and pulling the factors not dependent on the running index n out of the sum Mathematica still calculates

```
Exp[-(1/2) (x^2) - \[Lambda]^2 - I (1/2) t] 
Sum[HermiteH[n, x](\[Lambda] Exp[-I t])^n/n!,{n,0,Infinity}]
(* E^(-((I*t)/2)-x^2/2+(2*x*\[Lambda])/E^(I*t)-
\[Lambda]^2 - \[Lambda]^2/E^(2*I*t)) *)
```